# Buscar en MySql usando una lista desplegable select con php Ajax Jquery

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estoy realizando una busqueda `input`usando en jquery el evento `keyup`, ahora si en vez de input uso un `select` que evento usaría o como haría en ese caso?

Este es el input

```
<input type="text" name="pedido" class="form-control" id="pedido" required>
```

y este es el nuevo select

```
<select name="pedido" id="busquedas" class="form-control" required>
<option> </option>
<option>FD1</option>
<option>FD2</option>
<option>FD3</option>
</select>
```

Este es el jquery

```
    $(obtener_registros());
function obtener_registros(pedido)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax/ajax-consulta.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        data : { pedido: pedido },
        })
    .done(function(resultado){
        $("#datos_cliente").html(resultado);
    });
}
$(document).on('keyup', '#busquedas', function(){
    var valorBusqueda=$(this).val();
    if (valorBusqueda!="")
    {
        obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    }
    else
        {
            obtener_registros();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El evento que tienes que capturar es `change`.

```
$(document).on('change', '#busquedas', function(){
    var valorBusqueda=$(this).val();
    if (valorBusqueda!="")
    {
        obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    }
    else
    {
        obtener_registros();
    }
});
```

Y con esto te aseguras que `$(this).val()` tiene el valor que el usuario a seleccionado.

Puedes ver mas información del evento `change` en la [documentación oficial de JQuery.](http://api.jquery.com/change/)